# Can you write a program that will modify an Excel sheet?

Tags: java, excel

I'm trying to write a program for my dad that will take an excel sheet with a bunch of tabs in one file and turn it into several files with a couple tabs. Is there a way to do this? I was trying to do it in Java, but if there is a better way to do it, I'd be interested.

Comment: http://poi.apache.org/

Comment: Excel has a built-in macro language - VBA. See http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/create-a-macro.html for an intro.

Comment: I think there are OLE DB drivers for working with Excel files.

Comment: It's probably faster to copy the file a few times and delete the tabs you don't want from each one :/

Comment: @DavidPostill there's way more tabs than you are thinking about. Like thousands of tabs.

Comment: Yes , you can do lot with Excel, as mentioned you can use OLE DB drivers for Excel. I created one project for my friend. Transfering lot of date from 1 excel file to another following some rules. which also includes multiple tabs to multiple file.

But i did that in C#, i can send you the codeline if that would be any help to you.
Thanks

Comment: @PawanKumar id be interested to see that. thanks.

Comment: Your mail address please?

Comment: @PawanKumar wadebeastly3@yahoo.com

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org). It was used in a project I worked on (although I didn't directly use it) and it seemed to do it's job. It probably has what you're looking for.

Outside of Java, I have heard that powershell has good integration with excel, although I have never actually used it for that purpose. Here's an [article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/01/10/powershell-and-excel-fast-safe-and-reliable.aspx) about it.

Hope this helps! Good luck!

Comment: If its a one-off task, I'd look at VBA, though it might bog down with thousands of tabs.  In Java, yes, POI, or docx4j (disclaimer: I work on this), depending on whether you like XML Beans or JAXB.